# Getting data from items inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I humbly come to ask help with this doubt of mine:

I have a couple of divs (ej div id="infoDiv"), that have inside some inputs and `<p>` with ids too (ej id="delayInput").

The question here is: how can I access the data from an item inside a div? or should I make that the id from the item has a unique ID bound to the type of div that I am making (ej id="coverDelayInput"?

edit: here i leave a little snippet to show how im working and what i want to get:

```
<div class="text-left" id="coverDiv">
    <label>Orden:</label><p id="order">0</p>
    <br />
    <label for="delayInput">Delay:</label>
    <input type="text" id="delayInput" placeholder="delay (1 seg = 1000)" />
    <br />
    <label>Tipo de Página:</label>
    <p id="type">cover</p>
    <br />
</div>
```

as an example, i'm trying to console.log the cover tag text in jquery. with that example i'll be able to get the rest of the data
thak you again

Comment: You know ID's need to be unique right. Just use classes...

Comment: wouldn't that interfere with bootstrap classes?

Comment: Only when you are using the same names. If you're worried about that just restrict them with a prefix or a unique parent classname. But best practice aside you could just use querySelector to get it like ('#infoDiv #delayInput').

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show some example HTML and any attempts you've made to answer this question yourself. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to provide one here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You're making it yourself way too difficult for what it actually his. Considering you keep changing your question I will make this short:

"request getting ID's"

```js
const setup = () => {

    const types = document.querySelectorAll('.myType');
  
  const idList = [...types].reduce((list, myType) => {
    const key = myType.textContent;
    list[key] =  `${key}Div`;
    return list;
  }, {});
        
    console.log(idList);
  
  //so
  
  const coverDiv = document.querySelector(`#${idList.cover}`);
  const orderId = coverDiv.querySelector('.order').textContent;
  const inputValue = coverDiv.querySelector('.delayInput').value;
  
  console.log({orderId: orderId, inputValue: inputValue});
}

window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<div class="text-left" id="infoDiv">
    <label>Orden:</label><p class="order">0</p>
    <br />
    <label for="delayInput">Delay:</label>
    <input type="text" class="delayInput" placeholder="delay (1 seg = 1000)" />
    <br />
    <label>Tipo de Página:</label>
    <p class="myType">info</p>
    <br />
</div>

<div class="text-left" id="coverDiv">
    <label>Orden:</label><p class="order">0</p>
    <br />
    <label for="delayInput">Delay:</label>
    <input type="text" class="delayInput" placeholder="delay (1 seg = 1000)" />
    <br />
    <label>Tipo de Página:</label>
    <p class="myType">cover</p>
    <br />
</div>
```

Comment: He keeps changing it, this is the last time I undelete it.

Comment: i never deleted it ._.